# Using tomcat Can I check if my HTTP REQUEST is a valid Request to my web services?

Tags: java, swagger, tomcat8, restful-architecture, spring-restcontroller

Basically the TOMCAT response will be a "Bad Request 400" if I have any mistake in my REQUEST PARAMS, are there any solution to detect that mistake  **without writting a test code for the received REQUEST** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAVA validator is the solution : https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/

Answer (score 1):

At first, HTTP 400 were returned by web server only when HTTP protocol was not respected or at least the server was not able to recognize the request as a valid HTTP request. This check didn't need any test code to be program, it was embedded in the web server code.

Nowadays, when you are exposing a REST API, you are supposed to reuse these HTTP codes to represent the status of higher level request/responses exchanges. You may not need much code to validate a request, but you need to do it by yourself using a framework and some annotations for example if you are using java.

Comment: about the code i know what i can do but the question was that i want to know that error that make my REQUEST not a valid one for example a forgotten param or not good type of param.

Comment: The answer is you have to code for this, since it's not HTTP, it's a higher level exchange (REST/JSON/WS).